# Populate Field based on another Combo Box in grid of extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs5

In grid i have three column on column field have combo box and on change of combo box value auto populate another column respective field How to do this extjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHAZm.png)

Please see above image for grid code.

My Function is below

autoPopulateCsid: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row, action) {

/// i am not able to get whole record/row of grid which i am editing

}

i have to get record in function so i can update field of record and it will be dirty automatic. So on cancel i will discard all my changes for that perticular row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combobox `select` event don't have all these parameters, the parameters it actually receives are `combobox, newValue, oldValue, eOpts` from there you can get your "row record" from your editor componenet like this.

```
autoPopulateCsid: function(combobox, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
    let myRecord = combobox.up('editor').context.record;
     myRecord.set('collateralAgreement',newValue);

}
```

If you dont use myRecord.commit(), the record will be marked as dirty, after that if you want to discard those changes you can use `rejectChanges()` in the store of your grid.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: if i change values of myRecord.. how it will reflect in original grid?

Comment: Edited the answer to explain this, basically, you need to use `commit()` to commit the changes to the store of the grid

Comment: if i  set myRecord.set('collateralAgreement',newValue);
     myRecord.commit();
its not making field dirty in grid. i also want that field should be dirty if i update any record.

Comment: Sorry, if you want the record to be dirty, you don't need to use `commit`, updated the answer again.